# Black screen after closing lid and opening back, no response until hooked to power

Tags: 22.04, laptop, screen, lid

After I close the lid for a couple seconds using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - freshly installed today, and reopening - the screen is permanently black, pressing keys does not work, pressing/long pressing the power button doesn't work. The only thing that works is hooking the laptop to power and then long pressing the power button. I've had no such issue in windows, and the laptop is fairly new. I honestly thought my laptop got bricked until hooking it up 'revived' it. I need some help with this...

Hardware info -
HP HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-ds1xxx
AMD® Ryzen 7 4700u with radeon graphics